# Default Themes in Angular

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I'm new to Angular. I'm interested are there any default Themes in Angular 6 or 7?

I would like to use them in my Angular application.

Comment: Angular is a JS framework, theming is related to CSS. Find a framework or create your own, but Angular won't do it for you (you can integrate Angular material for instance, but it's not a native part of Angular).

Comment: here read this. https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Comment: @trichetriche you can theme in angular as well as create your own custom theme

Comment: @Roj Angular Material isn't Angular. Angular doesn't have a default theme.

Comment: hi peter start a chat with i will tell you how to make theme

Comment: @trichetriche except the response wasn't whether or not angular comes with a theme, it was if there are any default themes for angular 6 or 7 in which case there are using angular material, using color="primary | accent | warn", which has unique color schemes depending on which theme you're using. ie. `deeppurple-amber`,`indigo-pink`, etc. It also supports custom theming in which case you can assign your own scheme using the material design palettes.

Comment: @trichetriche also can you use angular material outside angular? of course not since it's a helper module specifically for angular, so don't say it isn't angular.

Comment: @Roj the title is literally `Default Themes in Angular`. There's no mention whatsoever of Material, neither in the title, nor in the question or the tags. I answered the question, you answered one that he didn't ask. And Material are guidelines, Angular Material is just the implementation of Material for Angular. You can use Material outisde of Angular. And again, no mention of Angular Material anywhere. Learn to let go when you're wrong dude.

Comment: Reading beyond title is called assumptions, and you're here to answer issues, not assumptions. I'm tired of you, you can't even read properly and are completely out of touch with the issue. Run `ng new example` and tell me where you see Angular Material in your package. Angular Material is a framework, as is Angular bootstrap. They are implementations of Material and Bootstrap, which are CSS guidelines that can be used without Angular. I don't have anymore time to loose with you. Good luck with your future projects.

Answer (score 2):

Angular itself does not offer any themes but you can make use of angular material (https://material.angular.io/). It comes with 4 predefined themes which you can use out of the box.

Or you can start creating your own themes (https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#defining-a-custom-theme)

Personally, I can recommend angular material as it integrates nicely with the angular ecosystem and follows best practices on component and theme development.

Answer (score 2):

Available pre-built themes in Angular Material:

```
deeppurple-amber.css
indigo-pink.css
pink-bluegrey.css
purple-green.css
```

If you're using Angular CLI, this is as simple as including one line in your **styles.css** file:

```
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

Alternatively, you can just reference the file directly. This would look something like:

```
<link href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
```